# How to delete Firebase storage file?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-storage

Have I missed something? Answers on the web does the same thing as me but....the download url no longer has an extension so my error says:

```
"error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found.  Could not delete object"
}
```

Code:

```
let url = demo[indexPath.row].downloadUrl
print(url) // shows the url

DataService.ds.REF_RECEIPTS.child(url).delete { (error) in
  if error != nil {
    print(error)
  }
}
```

That does not work. What other people has, and works, is the url = "demo.jpg", mine is just a string with a token but no file extension. If I go to the url I see the image so what's wrong?

Edit:

This is how I upload an image:

```
let receiptImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imagePlaceholder.image!, 0.2)
let metadata = FIRStorageMetadata()
metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"

let receiptUID = NSUUID().uuidString

DataService.ds.REF_RECEIPTS.child(CURRENT_USER!.uid + "_" + receiptUID).put(receiptImageData!, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in
    if let receiptDownloadedUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString {
        self.expenseData(receiptUrl: receiptDownloadedUrl)

        // Saving the image/receipt in local cache for faster access
        //guard let img = UIImage(data: receiptImageData!) else { return }
        //IMAGE_CACHE.setObject(img, forKey: receiptDownloadedUrl as NSString)
    }

}

func expenseData(receiptUrl: String) {...}
```

I've also tried `let receiptUID = NSUUID().uuidString + ".jpg"` but same issue.

Comment: What do you mean by, _the download url no longer has an extension_? Did they use to have extensions before? Can you post a sample of what your current url schema looks like?

Comment: Sure. I'll update with the upload method....

Comment: No extension as in a file extension.

Comment: That's more helpful.. When you do `print(url)`, what does the printed url look like? Can you provide a sample url?

Comment: It prints: `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/<APP-IDENTIFIER>83c37.appspot.com/o/receipts%2FZ0vsLScVlzSqRMLG2Ly9wb8BfiJ2_EC997BC7-A2A6-4F3C-9DB4-034625818924.jpg?alt=media&token=ac1b9ae6-e689-4236-9b08-a17575bd7286` I would see the image if viewed in a browser or on the iPhone. This is just an example.

Comment: After checking out your url, I'd say you should try rechecking your firebase app settings to see what the APP-ID is set to and confirm that it's similar to the one in Xcode because do you see how your url has the tag _<APP-IDENTIFIER>_? It seems like it wasn't set or something is wrong with it. Here's a sample URL from my project which includes my APP-ID along with the url. `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/codename-e494c.appspot.com/o/Profile%20Images%2FKCotGTGZIScXZ2qeoO1x8fojnf42.png?alt=media&token=ec0b9012-46b6-4ca8-a2a8-f2c05740981f`

Comment: No, I've replaced the actual name with `<APP-IDENTIFIER>‌` so no one could see the actual image.

Comment: Okay my bad. But does putting the full url and accessing the webpage through a browser result into an automatic download of the image? That was what I was trying to test.

Comment: No, It shows the image just fine. No automatic download.

Comment: I think it might be an issue with where you are referencing the deletion. In your save method, you're putting the image in the `(CURRENT_USER!.uid + "_" + receiptUID)` node. But when you're trying to delete it, your storage reference is from the `downloadURL` node which doesn't exist in your storage structure

Comment: Nahhh I've found it. Made a stupid mistake. I'll update.

Comment: @EmilDavid Thanks for the continued support!

Comment: Hi @Sylar. You can go ahead and [post an answer to your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) instead of editing it in the post. You can then mark it as accepted so that this question will be properly tagged. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 2):

I've made a mistake with the reference. I'm not an expert but I thought this ref should work: DataService.ds.REF_RECEIPTS.child().delete. What worked was:

```
let url = demo[indexPath.row].downloadUrl
let imageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: url)
imageRef.delete { (error) in
  if let error == error {
    // error
  } else {
    // success
  }
}
```

Little did I know was that `REF_RECEIPTS` was referencing the storage folder so that's the reason why I could `put` but not `delete`.

Comment: Thank you man, why .reference forUrl is not in the docs, I was gonna go nasty ways if I didn't see your answer.